# Why does my makefile never stop building?

Tags: makefile, build, rebuild

I am trying to create a makefile to control the build process. I use eclipse and I have a lot of projects some of which are shared libraries. So if I build a project that is using a library, then I would like the library to be built if it is out of date. The seems pretty standard. I just cannot make it work.
I am making the linking dependent on the libraries, and I (try to) provide a rule for building the libraries. But when I do it this way, it seems to be building the library over and over again - and it never finishes. What am I missing?

```
CPPUTEST_HOME = ...
PROJECTROOT := ...
SDKTARGETSYSROOT := /opt/fsl-imx-fb/4.14-sumo/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

COMPONENT_NAME := Jehova

USER_LIB := 

INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PROJECTROOT)/Log/source \
                $(PROJECTROOT)/Config/source \

LIBS :=         $(PROJECTROOT)/Log/bin/libLog.so \
                $(PROJECTROOT)/Config/bin/libConfig.so \

# Links to the commands to be used
REMOVE := rm -rf
COMPILER := arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
SOURCEDIR = source
OBJECTDIR = objects
TEST_DIR = utest
PATH_TO_MAIN = source/main.cpp

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJECTDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDENCIES = $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJECTDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# Paths to the headerfiles
get_dirs_from_dirspec = $(wildcard $1)

INCLUDE_DIRS += $(USER_LIB) \
                $(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)/usr/include/ \
                $(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/ \
                $(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/       

INCLUDE_DIR_EXPANDED = $(call get_dirs_from_dirspec, $(INCLUDE_DIRS))
COMPILE_INCLUDE = $(foreach dir, $(INCLUDE_DIR_EXPANDED), -I$(dir))
LINK_INCLUDE = $(foreach dir, $(INCLUDE_DIR_EXPANDED), -L$(dir))

# Compiler and linkerflags
COMPILER_FLAGS := -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 -Wno-unknown-pragmas --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)
LINKER_FLAGS := -mfloat-abi=hard -lpthread

# If main.cpp does not exist the project is assumed to be a shared library
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(PATH_TO_MAIN))","")
    COMPILER_FLAGS += -fPIC
    LINKER_FLAGS += -shared -o
    BIN := ./bin/lib$(COMPONENT_NAME).so
else
    LINKER_FLAGS += -o
    BIN := ./bin/$(COMPONENT_NAME)
endif

# Optimization and debug levels
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),release)
    COMPILER_FLAGS += -O3
else
    COMPILER_FLAGS += -O0 -g3
endif

# Include dependencies
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(DEPENDENCIES)),)
-include $(DEPENDENCIES)
endif
endif

# All Target
all: $(BIN) test
    -$(REMOVE) makeenv

# Compile source to create object files
./objects/%.o: ./source/%.cpp 
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
    -$(COMPILER) $(COMPILE_INCLUDE) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

# Link objects to build target
$(BIN): $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
    -$(COMPILER)  $(LINK_INCLUDE) --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(BIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# All Target release build
release: clean $(BIN)
    -$(REMOVE) makeenv

# Run the test
test: $(BIN)
    make -C $(TEST_DIR)

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(REMOVE) $(OBJECTS)$(DEPENDENCIES) $(BIN)
    make -C $(TEST_DIR) clean
    -$(REMOVE) makeenv
    -@echo ' '

$(LIBS):
    -cd $(PROJECTROOT)/Config && $(MAKE) clean all release
    -cd $(PROJECTROOT)/Log && $(MAKE) clean all release
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but (a) why are you prefixing all your lines with `-`?  This causes make to ignore errors which you definitely don't want to do (except maybe in `clean`), and (b) always use `$(MAKE)`, never `make`, when invoking sub-makes.

Comment: You're going to have to do more debugging on your own.  When you say "never ends" you mean you invoke make one time and it rebuilds the same targets over and over without returning to the shell prompt?  Or do you mean every time you invoke make it rebuilds the same targets then stops?  There's nothing in this makefile I can see that would cause the former behavior.  Maybe something in the `TEST_DIR` subdirectory makefile is causing it.  Try running make with `-d` and see why it keeps rebuilding (it will generate a lot of output).